# Converting tikz to PNG

Tags: tikz-pgf

**Hi all,**
**I am trying to convert an image tikz to png, but i don't know how to use shell escape in TeXStudio . I use imageMagik in Windows 10 OS.**

**How to compile my tex file with the option -shell-escape in TeXStudio and where I find my image after compilation.**

**This is an example :**

```
\documentclass[preview,border=4mm,convert={density=600,outext=.png}]{standalone} 
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[light, largesmallcaps]{kpfonts}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: You are not giving us much information on how your are creating your image and how many you have. Please extend your question with more information. Personally I perfer to make the imagemagik by hand on the commandline then I don't need to mess with shell escape (which can be a very dangerous setting)

Comment: @moumou85 AFAIK, on Windows, you could use a command such as `magick convert -density 400 input.pdf output.png`, or `magick convert -density 400 input.pdf -background white -alpha remove output.png` if you want to have transparency replaced with white. This works well with documents that look like `\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` (or with `0mm` or whatever you want—that's just an example).

Comment: where I find my image after compilation.

Comment: LaTeX creates a PDF, unless stated otherwise it will be right next to the `.tex` file you just compiled.

Comment: there is no image file next to tex file.

Comment: That is probably because shell escape is not enabled. It will tell you in the log file (the real log file, not the filtered view texmater is using). As frougon mentioned above you can manually convert the generated PDF using that command.

Comment: Hint: if you use @name then name will know you answered them, otherwise you'll have to wait until they come back (if they do).

Comment: I get `Class standalone Warning: Conversion failed! Please ensure that shell escape
(standalone)              is enabled (e.g. use '-shell-escape').` in the log as I don't compile with shell escape enabled

Comment: How can i enable '-shell-escape' option in TeXstudio, i dont find this option.

Comment: This may be called `-enable-write18`  depending on your distribution (or `--enable-write18`? sources diverge), but you didn't tell which one it is. As @daleif said, using ImageMagick on the command line is more secure than enabling shell escape, though.

Comment: How can i use ImageMagick on the command line, i only get PDF not image png.

Comment: You must first compile your LaTeX document to a PDF file as usual, then run one of the commands I gave [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532938/converting-tikz-to-png#comment1347600_532938). It should either give you a `.png` or print an error. These commands can be entered from `cmd.exe` (Google for command prompt, cmd.exe and the "cd" command if you don't know—cd is “change directory”). I believe you can open a command prompt from the Windows explorer nowadays, but I don't use Windows, so...

Comment: @moumou85 Run cmd command, then move to your folder of your pdf file, then run magick -density 960 x.pdf x.png